# chroot in C not working : EPERM Operation not permitted

Tags: c, posix, chmod

I am trying to use the *chroot* function in C, but it is giving me *EPERM* error.
MRE:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<sys/stat.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<errno.h>

int main(){
    int r;
    r=chdir(".");
    printf("%d\n",r);

    r=chroot(".");
    printf("%d\n",r);
    
    printf("%d\n",errno);
}
```

The output is:

```
0
-1
1
```

The last 1 means *EPERM* (Operation not permitted).

The expected output is:

```
0
0
0
```

Comment: May be your process does not have root user privileges? https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/chroot.2.html says only privileged user can l perform `chroot`.

Comment: BTW, `chdir(".")` doesn't do anything. `.` is always the current directory, so you're changing to where you already are.

Comment: Calling `printf()` can (and often does) change `errno`. If you want to get the error code from `chroot()`, you need to save `errno` before printing `r`.

Comment: @Barmar, maybe... that is the case? To check the value of the return when success, and then check what is the value when the thing fails.

Comment: @FaranAiki It's common to write something like `if (chroot(".") < 0) { perror("chroot"); exit(1); }`. If you need to do something before reporting the error, you have to save it. `r = chroot("."); save_errno = errno; printf("%d\n", r); if (r < 0) {printf("%d\n", save_errno); }`

Comment: @Barmar, that is assuming if I or the OP knows if `chroot` fails then it must `< 0`. Which in this case, I do not, but I do not know if OP knows it. For the second code, I think that is what the OP does, except they do not save the `errno`? I guess for a good code, I will do that, thanks for the information, though.

Comment: @FaranAiki That was my point, you *must* save `errno` because calling `printf()` will change it (since `printf()` performs system calls internally that can set `errno`).

Comment: @Barmar, yes, I understand that was your point; I will follow your advice (point) if I need to debug something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Linux **chroot**(2) man page says: *Only a privileged process (Linux: one with the CAP_SYS_CHROOT  capability) may call chroot().*  That might explain your difficulty, or part of it.

I rewrote your program:

```
#include<errno.h>
#include<limits.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>

#include<sys/stat.h>

int main(){
    int r;

    if( (r=chdir(".")) != 0 ) {
      perror("chdir");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    if( (r=chroot(".")) != 0 ) {
      perror("chroot");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    char dir[PATH_MAX];

    if( getcwd(dir, sizeof(dir)) == NULL ) {
      perror("getcwd");
      exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf( "changed root to %s\n", dir);
    
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

to illustrate some better choices.  If you're going to play with fire like **chroot**(2), you want to be prepared to use it carefully.

My program exits on first failure, because that's all that matters in a little test program (and often bigger ones, too).  It uses **perror**(3) to print the associated error string.  I personally prefer **err**(3) from the BSD library, and in larger programs I rely on `__func__` and `__LINE__` to tell me where the error occurred. I use `EXIT_FAILURE` because it's easier to search for than `1`.

I sort the `#include` directives to make it easier to see if something is already there.

Finally, my test prints some significant message at the end show the obtained result.  Here are two results:

```
$  ./main
chroot: Operation not permitted
$ sudo ./main
Password:
changed root to /
$
```

For extra credit: if chroot fails, print the results of `getpwuid(geteuid())` to see if the user that couldn't chroot is anything other than the superuser.

Comment: why getpwuid..?